# How to hide horizontal scroll bar in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I have in `iframe` horizontal scroll and I want to remove it . How can I make it possible? Only horizontal scroll bar: I want it to disappear. How can I do it? I've tried many examples but none of them working for me.

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      
    <style>
        #iframe{
     width:790px;
     height:1000px; 
     background: #FFFFFF;
     overflow-y:scroll;
    
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>

        <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
          
               <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="drop">
                    <a href="#">About us</a>

                </li>
                <li class="drop">
                    <a href="#">Contact us</a>

                </li>
                <li class="drop">
                    <a href="#">Services</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Address</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

      <div id="div1" style="width:772px; height:auto; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
          <iframe id="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  onload="window.scrollTo(0, 0)" src="http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx?hid=10000&chid=0&rate=IBE&css=brown" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
         </div>  

    </body>
```

Comment: Remove `scrolling` and try.

Comment: i removed it but nothing happened

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, try to be more specific please.

Comment: @d_z90 i need to disappear horizontal only not vertical

Comment: @ArindamNayak i need to disappear horizontal only not vertical.

Comment: i try many examples and i can not remove horizontalbar

Comment: I think I got your problem. I am going to post the answer in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems is linked with the css. This is how the code should look like:

```
#div1 {
    width: 772px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#iframe{
    width: 790px;
    height: 1000px; 
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The reason why you were having problems is because you should define the `overflow: scroll` for the upper `div1` containing your iframe. If you give it a `max-height` and define `overflow-y: scroll` and `overflow-y: hidden` it properly works.

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldpqh07x/).